# How to move user menu or welcome menu

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, css

How do I move the user or welcome menu to another location? I need to move the welcome menu to another location and make sure that java drop down gets moved with it too. how is it done?

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsEM0.png): [image]

Comment: What version of SP? Where do you want to move it? There is no java in SharePoint, you must mean Javascript

Comment: SharePoint 2010. I mean when you click on your name on the to right, you get a menu. (sorry if that is not java driven)

Comment: is it custom menu or OOTB? it is really good if you add screen shot...

Comment: where you want to move, from right to left?

Comment: in the s4-titletable area

Answer (score 1):

I added following right after the class s4-socialdata-notif which we are hiding. and that fixed the issue. thanks. I also added css to hide s4-ribbonrow in the head area.

```
<style type="text/css">
        #s4-ribbonrow
        {
            display: none;
        }   
    </style>



<td class="NewWelcomeMenu">
    <div class="s4-trc-container-menu">
      <div>
        <wssuc:Welcome id="IdWelcome" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
        </wssuc:Welcome>
        <wssuc:MUISelector ID="IdMuiSelector" runat="server"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```